# How do I add footnote in PDF report using python

Tags: python, pdf, footnotes

I need insert footnotes in my PDF report (using python).
The code would produce something like:

```
              1
This is a text .
```

and

```
1 This is a footnote
```

How I can do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Do you have a pdf document and you have to modify it?

Answer (score 0):

can this documentation help? [DOC](https://docs.python.org/devguide/documenting.html#footnotes)

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to use it. It doesn't work. How I use [#]_? ptext = '<font size=10>This is a paragraph with a footnote.</font>, [1]_ ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_y(-30) #30 CM from the bottom of the page
pdf.set_font('Arial', '', 8)
pdf.set_text_color(0)
pdf.cell(0, 5, '1 This is a footnote', 0, 0, 'C')
pdf.output("output 1")
```

This format will. properly align it to the footnote, you can change the adjust and the font type/size to a proper format [here](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/set_fill_color/index.html)
You can also add it to a method which can be called for any page.